# PSQL how to add steps into a table for a recipebook?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

If my database was for a recipebook how would i add all the steps into my tables?

[image: Recipe Table]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use second Table for this. The number of columns at your discretion. A one-to-many relationship will be used.
Scheme looks like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQFrZ.png

Comment: if possible could you have a look at my erd for improvements or errors. 
Thank you.
https://i.imgur.com/PtXtHx6.jpg